# can I carbonate a keg with my own cider

Tags: carbonation, cider, bottles, kegs

I have a no of kegs both 50L and 30L kegs from my own private bar ,I'm just wondering if I can carbonate my own cider in the keg similar to carbonating to the  bottles of cider 
cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: Why not? What makes you think it would not work?

Comment: Unless there's a specific person stopping you with a mallet, no, you are free to do as you please. Maybe make sure they're sanitised first though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have kegs, why not just use CO2 to carb it?  That's what I do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to carbonate your keg using priming sugar, there are several posts with a lot of information already:

- [carbonation in a 5 gallon keg with priming sugar](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/20510/carbonation-in-a-5-gallon-keg-with-priming-sugar/20514#20514)
- [Using a keg for secondary fermentation and natural carbonation](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1767/using-a-keg-for-secondary-fermentation-and-natural-carbonation)
- [why is less bottling sugar required when naturally carbonating in a keg...](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12899/why-is-less-bottling-sugar-required-when-naturally-carbonating-in-a-keg-versus-b)